# Erros in pmg regression

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have the following kind of panel dataset.

```
> head(fund_panel)
      month  months           fund_name                     return ex_mkt_ret id
    1     1 01-1998 27four Shari'ah Active Eq. Prescient A1     NA   -0.21268  1
    2     2 02-1998 27four Shari'ah Active Eq. Prescient A1     NA    0.06325  1
    3     3 03-1998 27four Shari'ah Active Eq. Prescient A1     NA   -0.04369  1
    4     4 04-1998 27four Shari'ah Active Eq. Prescient A1     NA   -0.02485  1
    5     5 05-1998 27four Shari'ah Active Eq. Prescient A1     NA   -0.11840  1
    6     6 06-1998 27four Shari'ah Active Eq. Prescient A1     NA   -0.34746  1
```

R shows mistake for the following Fama-Macbeth regression using the package `plm` and its function `pmg`:

```
> fpmg <- pmg(return ~ ex_mkt_ret, fund_panel, index=c("month", "id")) ##Fama-MacBeth
Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
  duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
2: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)
```

I came across the internet to overcome the problem but i can't figure out. Please, your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message given should be quite obvious:
`duplicate couples (id-time)`

This means you have rows in your data set that specify the same time period (at least) twice for the same individual (say, an observation for individual 1 in year 2016, 2017, 2018, 2018).

However, when looking at your data set and how you specify the index for the estimation command (see `?pmg`), it seems like you want to have the column `id` as the individual index and `month` as the time index. The argument `index`to `pmg` takes the individual index at the first position and the time index at thes second position. Thus, flipping `id` and `time` should work:

`fpmg <- pmg(return ~ ex_mkt_ret, fund_panel, index=c("id", "month"))`